# Best practices for a find-function (in the model of a MVC)

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, model

I'm currently working on a project that is somewhat small, but not tiny. We have decided to go for a MVC architecture but a framework like CI or the like seems like an overkill.

So I decided to make my own framework that is considerably more simple.

The problem I have is with the Model class and more specifically the "get record" part.

What would you say is the best practise to construct such a function?

I've come up with a few alternatives myself:

1:
make a function like cakePHP's `find($fields,$params)`

2:
make a function with loads of params, like `find($table,$fields,$join,$where,$order,$limit,$offset)`
each with a relevant default

3:
Pure query function that makes you just pass a select statement

The project is made in PHP with a MySQL db connection. I'm using WordPress as a base for the page itself and the project is a plugin.

It's a big question and I would be really grateful for any pointer in the right direction.

Comment: definitely not this one `find($table,$fields,$join,$where,$order,$limit,$offset)` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not looking at wordpress's methods and try to reuse/extend them ?

- there's probably a DB layer
- there are existing methods for querying.

Personnaly I would take a look there first

Comment: Wordpress have good functions for updating and inserting but leaves fetching to 3 functions: get_var,get_row and get_result. But all 3 uses pure queries to fetch results. Is it really good practise to use it like that or is it better to try to break down the queries in variables?

Comment: Considering the popularity of wordpress, I think it might be considered as a good practice. But for your particular neer, you may wish to add another layer...